# pgpool load balancing is sending all queries only to master

Tags: postgresql, pgpool, load-balancing

My two postgresql servers are configured for streaming replication, which is working fine.

Pgpool is configured for Master Slave mode / Load Balance Mode.

**pgpool.conf:**

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 9999
backend_hostname0 = 'master-postgres-ip'
backend_port0 = port-no
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_data_directory0 = 'data-dir'
backend_hostname1 = 'slave-postgres-ip'
backend_port1 = port-no
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = 'data-dir'
load_balance_mode = on
master_slave_mode = on
master_slave_sub_mode='stream'
```

I expected all write queries will go to primary and read queries will be distributed between two. But, all the queries are going only to master. However, if I stop master, queries are going to slave.

Can somebody tell me what might be going wrong?

pgpool gives below log on startup:

```
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 1
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: DEBUG:  SSL is requested but SSL support is not available
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: DEBUG:  authenticate kind = 3
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
2015-11-03 17:25:56: pid 21284: DEBUG:  find_primary_node: no primary node found
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initially, I have set `sr_check_period` in `pgpool.conf` to 0 (zero) to disable SR checking. I thought of avoiding this check and invariably balance the load. But this has caused the problem.

After I have given a non-zero value to this attribute, load balancing started working.

Comment: There are two sample files of pgpool.conf for master-slave mode viz. pgpool.conf.sample-master-slave and pgpool.conf.sample-stream. First one has to be used when replication software is slony and the latter is for streaming replication. I was wrongly using the first one. When I used the second file as a reference, everything has started working smooth. We don't need to worry about sr_check_period explicitly as it comes with non-zero default value.

Answer (score 1):

`backend_hostname1 = 'master-postgres-ip'` - > This should point to your slave, not the master again.

Comment: I edited my question now. Sorry for that. In my actual setup, I am rightly pointing to slave IP.